# composer install not executed by docker build

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a laravel image with docker build. Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.14-fpm

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /tmp

RUN touch ./resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less \
&& mv ./.env.local ./.env \
&& mv ./.dockerignore-local ./.dockerignore \
&& apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git npm \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev vim --no-install-recommends \
&& apt-get purge --auto-remove -y g++ \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt -j$(nproc) gd

RUN  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash \
&& export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" \
&& [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm \
&& nvm install node \
&& npm cache clean -f && npm install -g n && n stable && npm install cross-env && npm install && npm run dev

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
&& composer install --no-interaction

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
        /app/storage \
        /app/bootstrap/cache \
&& chmod 755 /tmp/entrypoint.sh

CMD ["/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
```

but when I execute it with:

```
docker build -f laravel-local.dockerfile . -t xoco/kendozone:local-1.0.0 --no-cache
```

Composer install is not doing anything:

```
Step 7/9 : RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && composer install --no-interaction
 ---> Running in 90d05a566269
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.6.3) successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize
Removing intermediate container 90d05a566269
 ---> 7665c4fefb57
```

I don't understand this behaviour. I have a .dockerignore that has vendor folder inside, so I don't know why shouldn't it install composer dependecies:

```
vendor/
node_modules/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
storage/*.key
storage/framework/cache/**
storage/framework/sessions/**
storage/framework/views/**
.env
.idea
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And the file composer.json has all the required packages there?

Comment: What happens if after all is installed, you run a bash and manually run composer install?

Comment: It appears I had to delete vendor/  and node_module folders.

As those folder are in .gitignore, they are not copied in the docker image, but somehow, Laravel still think I have the folders up to date, so it think there is nothing to do.

Comment: Hm, interesting